# How can I achieve a bibliography sorted by appearance with BiBLaTeX according to the IEEE reference system?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, numbering, ieee-style

I'm writing a thesis with `\documentclass{report}` on Overleaf and I am using the IEEE reference system, that has references as numbers, i.e. [1], [2], [3] etc. According to several reference guides for IEEE (for example the following [[1](https://libguides.murdoch.edu.au/IEEE/text)],[[2](https://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/ieeereferencing/gettingstarted)],[[3](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf)],[[4](https://ieee-dataport.org/sites/default/files/analysis/27/IEEE%20Citation%20Guidelines.pdf)]), "Citations are numbered in the order in which they appear in the text".

This is however, not what happens in my text. Instead they seem to be numbered alphabetically. So the first reference in the whole document does not get number [1] unless I change the author name to something like "Aaa". But I want the first reference in the text to get number [1] (and the following references to be in the order which they appear) no matter what the author names are.

I `\usepackage{biblatex}` and have all the references in `\bibliography{references.bib}`

My questions:

- Why aren't the references numbered in the order which they
  appear?
- What do you need to add (or remove?) to make
  the references be numbered in the order that they appear?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! You need to use `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you just load `biblatex` as `\usepackage{biblatex}` with no further options, you get the default `style=numeric, sorting=nty,` behaviour, which means that you get numeric citations and a bibliography that is sorted by name-title-year. In particular citations are not sorted by appearance. You can get sorting by citation order with `sorting=none,`. But as Alan comments, if you want full IEEE style, just say `style=ieee,` - no further options are required (`style=ieee,` sets `sorting=none,` automatically).

Comment: @AlanMunn Do you want to type up a quick answer here?